# Pressing CMD + Folder from dock opens finder at bottom page

Tags: macos, finder, dock

When I press Command and click on a folder in the Dock, Finder should come up and show me it's location there. However, Finder shows up and the page is scrolled all the way to the buttom. So I have to scroll up to find the folder. The files are supposed to be arranged by Date Added. So new files are on top, and finder always starts from the bottom when a Folder is opened from Dock.

Why does this happen and how can I ensure that the folder accessed through the Dock is always shown in the first page of Finder ?

Please let me know if I should clarify further.

Comment: Did you try deleting the hidden .DS_store file for the default finder window? That should clear up what you are seeing.

Comment: @bmike How do I do that ?

Comment: Take your pick :) http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=Delete+.ds_store

Comment: @bmike thanks :) I tried replicating the bug but failed. Seems like the issue has been fixed with Mavericks !